# How can I instruct yum to install a specifc version of OpenJDK

Tags: java, redhat

I trying to install **openjdk** in the **redhat** server, how can I install the specified version?

The version I want to install is: **11.0.4**

The version installed using the following command is **11.0.6**

```
yum install java-11-openjdk-devel
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151689/how-can-i-instruct-yum-to-install-a-specific-version-of-package-x

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use yum.  This is system admin, not programming. See unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Since this is the first time asking a question, I am sorry for the incorrect question!

Comment: That's OK.  Now you know a better place to ask system admin questions :-)   Though here's a clue: I found that Q&A by googling.  Indeed, google even suggested the search terms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Worked with

```
yum --showduplicates list java-11-openjdk-devel

yum install java-11-openjdk-devel-11.0.4.11-1.el7_7
```