# How to find list of all openjdk versions and install specific version in redhat/linux?

Tags: java, linux, redhat

First where can I see all openjdk versions are available?

Second how to install specific version fastest way? (usually I download rpm and install from that)

Thanks.

Comment: Found One solution from here: https://access.redhat.com/downloads/content/package-browser

Comment: ah this one is nicer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59781397/5419748